# selenium: css query

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-rc

```
<b>
<s>
   <b>---</b> (1)
   <b>---</b> (2)
</s>
</b>
<s>
   <b>---</b> (3)
   <b>---</b> (4)
</s>
```

1. I would like to could  tags but only the ones which are children of  tag? 
   How do I specify the css in this case?
   Is this ok: `self.selenium.get_css_count("css=s b")`
   Would this count all  s b relationships, with s as parent and b as child. 4 in the above example? If not, could you help with this issue?
2. I would like to click the fourth (4)  tag under  tag. How would I do that?
   if I do: `self.selenium.click("css=s b:nth(1))` 
   it would select (2), so how do i specify `(s b):nth(3)`?
   Because s is parent of b. and I want to click on the fourth kind of this relationship.
   I hope this makes sense.
3. what is the difference between nth() and nth-of-type()

Thanks
Sunny

Answer (score 0):

You could use xpaths rather than css selectors to do this.

for your 1.

```
get_xpath_count("//s/b")
```

and 2.

```
click("//s[2]/b[2]")
```

Answer (score -1):

What about:

b > s:first-child > b

To click 4th child:

:nth-child(4)

3rd question: [nth-of-type vs nth-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313769/nth-of-type-vs-nth-child)