# Need to select second table's second row using CSS selectors

Tags: html, css

I have an *HTML* table as below :

```
<table class="reference notranslate">
  <tr>..</tr>
     .
     .
  <tr>..</tr>
</table>
<table class="reference notranslate">
  <tr>..</tr>
     .
     .
  <tr>..</tr>
</table>
<table class="reference notranslate">
  <tr>..</tr>
     .
     .
  <tr>..</tr>
</table>
```

I know the *XPATH* : `//table[@class = 'reference notranslate'][2]/tr[2]`

I want to select second table's second row. Can any one help how to write the *CSS selectors* from the same?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> "I know the XPATH : `//table[@class = 'reference notranslate'][2]/tr[2]`
>
> I want to select second table's second row. Can any one help how to
>   write the CSS selectors from the same?"

So, you mean like:

```
table.reference.notranslate:nth-child(2) tr:nth-child(2)
```

This selects the second descendant `tr` element of the second table which has both classes (`reference` and `notranslate`).

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/J3Qfq/1/).

Comment: @Priti Ahh ok. That just means the element has both classes, reference and notranslate. See this example I made for you - http://jsfiddle.net/J3Qfq/2/

Comment: what the means of `nth-child(2)` ? if you don't mind,could you tell me the difference between `nth-of-type(2)` and `nth-child(2)` ?

Comment: @Priti No worries, here is a great short answer which explains it better than I could in a comment xD - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9313956/1586880

Answer (score 5):

```
table.reference:nth-of-type(2) tr:nth-child(2)
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
table.reference:nth-child(2) tr:nth-child(2)
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

[Js Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JrRCe/)

Comment: I need the `xpath` equivalent *css*.