# React Table (Tanstack) apply class to th element conditionally

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

I am using @tanstack/react-table v8.5.13. I am trying to do something really simple here but seems to find no way how to do it in documentation.

My table has two headers (A header and a subheader defined below)

```
const columnHelper = createColumnHelper<ITableData>();

const columns = [
  columnHelper.group({
    id: 'Header',
    header: () => <Button variant='outlined'>Show all</Button>,
    columns: [
      columnHelper.accessor('header_sublevel', {
        header: () => <span>Secondary Header</span>,
        cell: (info) => info.getValue()
      })
    ]
  })
];
```

I am rendering the data by doing this.

```
export default function MyTableComponent {
  const data = useAppSelector(state => state.table.data);
  const table = useReactTable<IListPrice>({
    data: listPriceData,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel()
  });

  return (
    <div
      ref={virtualizedTableContainerRef}
      style={{ padding: '1rem' }}
      className='virtualized-table-container'
    >
      <table>
        <thead>
          {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr key={headerGroup.id}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                <th
                  key={header.id}
                  colSpan={header.colSpan}
                >
                  {header.isPlaceholder
                    ? null
                    : flexRender(header.column.columnDef.header, header.getContext())}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
            <tr key={row.id}>
              {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                <td key={cell.id}>{flexRender(cell.column.columnDef.cell, cell.getContext())}</td>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          {table.getFooterGroups().map((footerGroup) => (
            <tr key={footerGroup.id}>
              {footerGroup.headers.map((header) => (
                <th key={header.id} colSpan={header.colSpan}>
                  {header.isPlaceholder
                    ? null
                    : flexRender(header.column.columnDef.footer, header.getContext())}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tfoot>
      </table>
      <div className='h-4' />
    </div>
  );
```

**What do I want?** I am trying to add a class to the second row of `th` elements in order to style them. Below is what's rendered in the generated HTML code.

[image: Rendered HTML code]

**What I've tried so far?**
One solution I could think of is depending on the depth of headers I could apply class but seems like its an overkill. Thoughts?

There's no `getHeaderProps` method available on header which used to be available in v7 of react-table. Is it moved or removed in v8?

Comment: Is targeting with CSS an [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633959/need-to-select-second-tables-second-row-using-css-selectors)?

Comment: Or you can add an index to `map`  like `{table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup, trIndex)`  Then check if `trIndex === 1` and apply the class

Comment: CSS selection is an option but some styles are dependent on whether the current th is part of the subheader. Anyway, v7 version of the table had methods like getHeaderProps which enabled adding props to the th element, they don't seem to be present in v8 of react table