# Elements have twice the index in nth-child that they should

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, haml, selector

I'm trying to print records from a database in HAML and style them with `.scss` tags relative to their index, like so:

```
- i = 0
    - @records.each do |record|
        - i += 1

        :scss
            .win:nth-child(#{i}) {
                background-color: #{record.background}

                p {
                    color: #{record.font_color}
                }
            }

        .win
          %p This is styled entry
```

Something weird happened where only the first half of the records were being styled and not in chronological order.

What I realized is that it was skipping every first iteration because none of the `.win` elements had an index with an odd number, their indexes were all multiples of two.

I figured that there were somehow twice as many `.win` elements as there ought to be but there aren't. There's one for every record just like you'd expect.

I don't know what's happening but I'll take a shot in the dark and say that when HAML is parsing the file it's recognizing the ".win" in the scss tag and recognizes that as a `.win` element.

Comment: Try `nth-of-type` instead

Comment: That worked. Any reason you posted a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313769/nth-of-type-vs-nth-child

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `nth-of-type` instead if you are only counting elements of one class.  `nth-child` counts all elements of a parent, and then triggers if your chosen selector is in one of nth locations.

Comment: :nth-of-type does no such thing.  The nth-of-type family selectors only select the elements of a specific element (eg. p, div, etc.).  What you're looking for is an nth-of-class, which doesn't exist.