# nth-of-type css selector to target the first element of a class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to understand why this `nth-of-type` selector isn't working as expected. My goal is to make the first `.row` element red, and all others after the first blue, while leaving the items in green as they are.

https://jsfiddle.net/darrengates/pa34zyjd/14/

```css
.wrapper div {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.wrapper .row:nth-of-type(n+1) {
  background-color: red;
}
.wrapper .row:nth-of-type(n+2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="option">option</div>
  <div class="button">some button</div>
  <div class="row">I wanna be red</div>
  <div class="row">I wanna be blue</div>
  <div class="row">I wanna be blue</div>
  <!-- all other row elements after the first should be blue -->
</div>
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9313956/7094618) could help you understand.

Comment: clearest and best description I've yet found is here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nth-of-type vs nth-child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313769/nth-of-type-vs-nth-child); *this [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9313845/6381711) your question and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42170738/6381711) answer by [Pangloss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483779/pangloss) may be the best approach based on your scenario.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `n-th-of-type` selector refers to the **tag type** on the same level, *not* the class, in this case the `div` tags which are siblings inside `.wrapper`. Therefore you need this CSS, since they are the third and fourth `div` in there:

```
.wrapper .row:nth-of-type(n+3) {
  background-color: red;
}
.wrapper .row:nth-of-type(n+4) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cb3qd8t6/

Answer (score 2):

`nth-*` selectors only look for the type of the element not the class name. In your example, I would use `~` or `+` to do it:

```css
.wrapper div {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.wrapper .row {
  background-color: red;
}
.wrapper .row ~ .row {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="option">option</div>
  <div class="button">some button</div>
  <div class="row">I wanna be red</div>
  <div class="row">I wanna be blue</div>
  <div class="row">I wanna be blue</div>
  <!-- all other row elements after the first should be blue -->
</div>
```