# Selection of elements using nth-child selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-selectors

```js
$(".sidebar>i:nth-child(3)").on("click", showMenu);
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
 <div class="colorPalette">
   <button class="submit">Submit</button>
  <p>Color Pallette:</p><br />
  <div class="colors_1">
   <span id="color1"></span>
   <span id="color2"></span>
   <span id="color3"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="colors_2">
    <span id="color4"></span>
   <span id="color5"></span>
   <span id="color6"></span>
  </div> 
 </div>
 <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left" title="Back to Menu"></i>
</div>
```

I need to select the 2nd  (Back to Menu) button. So why nth-child(3) works but not nth-child(2)?

Comment: The answers are good, though using a complex selector like that might not be a good idea to begin with. I'd consider using [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get1) instead, for readability. `$('.sidebar > i').get(2).on('click', showMenu)` would get the second `i` element

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nth-of-type vs nth-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313769/nth-of-type-vs-nth-child)

Comment: @kingdaro Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `:nth-child(n)` selects all children inside a parent element, regardless of what they are. So, in your case:

```
.sidebar>i:nth-child(3)
// This is the 3rd child, i tag

.sidebar>i:nth-child(2)
// This is the 2nd child, div tag
```

```js
console.log($('.sidebar>i:nth-child(1)')[0])
console.log($('.sidebar>:nth-child(2)')[0])
console.log($('.sidebar>i:nth-child(2)')[0])
console.log($('.sidebar>i:nth-child(3)')[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
  <div class="colorPalette">Test</div>
  <i class="fa fa-arrow" title="Back to Menu"></i>
</div>
```

What you need is actually `:nth-of-type()` selector.

```js
console.log($('.sidebar>i:nth-of-type(1)')[0])
console.log($('.sidebar>i:nth-of-type(2)')[0])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar">
  <i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
  <div class="colorPalette">
    Test
  </div>
  <i class="fa fa-arrow" title="Back to Menu"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

From [JQuery's docs](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

> The :nth-child(n) pseudo-class is easily confused with :eq(n), even though the two can result in dramatically different matched elements. With :nth-child(n), all children are counted, regardless of what they are, and the specified element is selected only if it matches the selector attached to the pseudo-class. With :eq(n) only the selector attached to the pseudo-class is counted, not limited to children of any other element, and the (n+1)th one (n is 0-based) is selected.