# Styling buttons with nth-child()

Tags: html, css

How do I style the nth button in this HTML:

```
<div class="k-klas">
<div>
    <p>
        <button>Inschrijven</button>
    </p>
<div>
<div>
    <p>
        <button>Inschrijven</button>
    </p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>
        <button>Inschrijven</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

width this CSS:

```
.k-klas button:nth-child(1) {background:#f00;}
.k-klas button:nth-child(2) {background:#0f0;}
```

both buttons will be red...

Comment: did you properly closed divs ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nth-of-type vs nth-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313769/nth-of-type-vs-nth-child)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not targeting the buttons properly.

The buttons are always the *first* child. That is to say, the first (and only) child of the `p` tags are the buttons.

You need to target the `div`s they live in, since it's those that have multiple siblings.

```
.k-klas div:nth-child(1) button { background:#f00; }
.k-klas div:nth-child(2) button { background:#0f0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML is not correct. You need to close the first tag of div

And you need to use nth-child() for div instead of button.

```css
.k-klas div:nth-child(1) button {background:#f00;}
.k-klas div:nth-child(2) button {background:#0f0;}
.k-klas div:nth-child(3) button {background:#000;}
```

```html
<div class="k-klas">
  <div>
      <p>
          <button>Inschrijven 1</button>
      </p>
  </div>
  <div>
      <p>
          <button>Inschrijven 2</button>
      </p>
  </div>
  <div>
      <p>
          <button>Inschrijven 3</button>
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best I've  come up with is  :

```
.k-klas div:nth-child(1) button {background:#f00;}
.k-klas div:nth-child(2) button {background:#0f0;}
```

Div's you are looking not buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Try to target the immediate child of `.k-klas` div.

```
.k-klas>div:nth-child(1) button{
  background: #f00;
}

.k-klas>div:nth-child(2) button{
  background: #0f0;
}
```

'>' selector is used to select the immediate child in css.