# Selecting divs in a div without use of class or ID

Tags: html, css

```
<div>
   <div>A</div>
   <div>B</div>
   <div>C</div>
 </div>    

 <div>
   <div>A</div>
   <div>B</div>
   <div>C</div>
 </div>
```

A should be colored red, B should be colored green and C should be colored blue. Now I can easily fix this if I use a class or ID, but what if for some reason I don't want to use a single class/id? I know it's possible, but can't figure it out for the life of it.

I probably have to use something with child selectors, but it keeps not working out properly and I'm close to having tried out all possible combinations.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313769/nth-of-type-vs-nth-child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nth-child` is the solution for that

this will allow you to select element according to their position to their parent

```css
div div:nth-child(1){
  color:red;
}

div div:nth-child(2){
  color:green;
}

div div:nth-child(3){
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <div>A</div>
   <div>B</div>
   <div>C</div>
 </div>    

 <div>
   <div>A</div>
   <div>B</div>
   <div>C</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I used nth-child as my first attempts, but it did not work as I expected. What I'm actually doing differed slightly from my question, I'm trying is to give the div that contains the 3 div a border, while giving each of the 3 div (and those only) a different background color.

div: first-child{
border: 1px solid;
height: 50px;

div div:nth-child(1){
height: 50px;
width: 33%;
background-color: red;
position: relative;
float: left;
clear: right;

Second child div is the same except with clear: both, and the third child div has float: right and clear: left.