# Select one div after another css selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have been trying to do this for a while and feel it should be fairly simple:

```
<div id = "container">
  <div id = "item1" class = "item"> </div>
  <div id = "item2" class = "item"> </div>
  <div id = "item3" class = "item"> </div>
</div>
```

How can I select each item one after another and assign each a different `background` (without using `id`s)?

What I am trying to achieve:

```css
#item1 {
  background: red;
}

#item2 {
  background: blue;
}

#item3 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="item1" class="item"> </div>
  <div id="item2" class="item"> </div>
  <div id="item3" class="item"> </div>
</div>
```

But isn't there a way to select each element in the `#container` div one by one, regardless of it's `id` value? By doing something such as the following :

```
.container:nth-child(1){ /*select first child of .conainter (#item1) ?*/
background: red;
}
```

or

```
.item:nth-of-type(2){ /*select second element of type .item (#item2) */
background: blue;
}
```

Comment: I, too, like to see what you think should work first. Also, this description on its own isn't enough to know what you're trying to accomplish. Is this a repeating pattern? Or does each one get a unique background? If you're going for the latter, why not just use IDs? What happens if you have more children than you do backgrounds?

Comment: @CoryCoolguy I have added more info and showed what I meant by nth-child and nth-of-type

Comment: In reply to your edits, no, Your not doing your CSS correctly. To use nth types you have to specify to inside values. adding nth type to the container wont work as your essentially saying i want the second or third container to be red etc. Look at the below anwsers as they provide 3 CORRECT uses that all work.

Comment: duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313769/nth-of-type-vs-nth-child

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nth-of-type vs nth-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313769/nth-of-type-vs-nth-child)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Yes you can do either method to select the items as you've described. What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to do this with only CSS:

```
.item:nth-of-type(1) { background: #fff}
.item:nth-of-type(2) { background: #000}
.item:nth-of-type(3) { background: #abc}
```

If you want to grab these after the fact using JS and/or jQuery:

```
jQuery(".item").each(function(i, el) {
   if(i == 0) {
      el.style.backgroundColor = "black";
   } else {
      el.style.backgroundColor = "red";
   }
})
```

`i` here would be the index of your `.item` elements so you can target which one you need by this index (hence the conditional)

Also note that you need to set a height on the `.item` elements or add some content if you want to see the background color change. The height by default is 0

Comment: wasn't me @adr5240

Comment: I'll give you a 1 up, since your answer is better than mine :)

Comment: No worries @user3131132 and thank you both. Would you mind marking this as an answer for visibility?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this in CSS and JS. Below, is my variation I would normally use on client websites to achieve this background variation you are attempting to achieve:

```
#container div {width: 200px; height: 200px;}
#container div:first-child {background-color: red;}
#container div:nth-child(2) {background-color: green;}
#container div:last-child {background-color: blue;}
```

Im using first child and last childs on the first and last elements inside #container and then for the one in the middle i just tell the browser to find the second div inside #container.

Here is my HTML so my explination and CSS makes sense:

```
<div id = "container">
 <div>ITS RED! </div>
 <div>ITS GREEN! </div>
 <div>ITS BLUE! </div>
</div>
```

Feel free to edit and play around with my code in a jsfiddle enviroment: https://jsfiddle.net/x9eouw7z/

Comment: I like this answer. It might not have been the answer they were looking for, but it answers the question per the asker's parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For a static page you can use the `:nth-child()` selector like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/6brcg9p7/3/

```
.item:nth-child(1) {
  background: blue;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
}
```