# Nth-Child: odd/even on children and children of children

Tags: html, css

I have a layout that due to the layout there are "children of children". The layout works well on desktop, but on the mobile version I would like the "captions" to alternate background colors. I know how to do the media queries etc to trigger the mobile version, but having troubles with the alternating background colors as my HTML has children and children below children divs.

The below code is the most stripped down version that I could do that would show the issue that I'm experiencing. I removed the img and href URLs but they are in the final code. This code is specifically for mobile that is why the images are hidden in CSS.

I'm sure its something obvious that I just can't think of.

Please note I'm not looking to do a major overhaul of the HTML as the design was very specific that was a pain to make responsive.

Thank You.

```css
.featured-banner span {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.featured-banner img {
  display: none;
}

.featured-banner:nth-child(odd) span {
  background: rgba(72, 68, 69, 1);
  color: #ffffff;
}

.featured-banner:nth-child(even) span {
  background: rgba(142, 32, 45, 1);
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="featured">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="line-bg">
      <h2></h2>
      <h3></h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="featured-col col-sm-3"><a target="_self" title="Test" href="" class="featured-banner"><span class="dark">Test</span><img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="Test"></a></div>
      <div class="featured-col col-sm-6">
        <div class="featured-col col-sm-5"><a target="_self" title="Test" href="" class="featured-banner"><span class="red">Test</span><img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="Test"></a></div>
        <div class="featured-col col-sm-7"><a target="_self" title="Test" href="" class="featured-banner"><span class="light">Test</span><img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="Test"></a></div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="featured-row">
          <div class="featured-col col-sm-7"><a target="_self" title="Test" href="" class="featured-banner"><span class="light">Test</span><img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="Test"></a></div>
          <div class="featured-col col-sm-5"><a target="_self" title="Test" href="" class="featured-banner"><span class="dark">Test</span><img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="Test"></a></div>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="featured-col-right featured-col col-sm-3"><a target="_self" title="Test" href="" class="featured-banner"><span class="red">Test</span><img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="Test"></a></div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using Bootstrap? And CSS pseudo classes match elements, not classes of elements. Adding a class makes it act like a filter

Comment: Not gonna happen with CSS- You need JS I suspect - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313769/nth-of-type-vs-nth-child and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector

Comment: What you've missed here is that `nth-child()` (and similar) works among siblings sharing the same parent, which your `.featured-banner` doesn't. Your `featured-col` elments does though.

Comment: I found another solution, simply hardcode odd/even classes into the HTML and target them in the media queries. Thanks everyone for the assistance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although this was my problem, I'm going to answer my question instead of closing it just in case someone comes across the issue with children of children also.

I have used nth-child in the past so that was what really annoyed me.

Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best ones.

My simple solution was to hard code odd/even classes into the divs and just target them in the media query. That way they can still be alternated without the need of using javascript.