# CSS Nth of Type not targetting

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to apply specific mobile styling to every second occurrence of the "marketplace_item_container" class shown with the structure below:

```css
.exploreMiddleSection div:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="exploreMiddleSection">
  <a href="">
    <div class="marketplace_item_container">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="marketplace_item_container">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </a>
  <a href="">
    <div class="marketplace_item_container">
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

I'm aware that I can't target specific classes with nth-of-type and only standard html elements so I've tried the above but it's not working.

How can I properly target every second occurrence of "marketplace_item_container" class?

Comment: First thing to note: structural pseudo-classes, like `nth-child()` and `:nth-of-type()` work only on *siblings*. If the list of elements you're targeting don't share the same parent, this selector won't work. Consider targeting the anchor elements instead, as they represent a list of siblings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `div` is the only direct child of `a`, try this:

```
.exploreMiddleSection a:nth-of-type(2) .marketplace_item_container {margin-right:0;}
```

Comment: thanks! I always really confused over these nth-of-type rules

Comment: Glad i could help. You can read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313769/nth-of-type-vs-nth-child for further info (:

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is not working because the div isn't a direct child of exploreMiddleSection.

.`exploreMiddleSection a div:nth-of-type(2) {margin-right:0;}`