# css selectors nth-child data

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="wholePrice">
<div class="myPrice"><div class="symbol">'+d.symbol+'</div><div class="price">'+d.price+'</div></div>
<div class="myPrice"><div class="symbol">'+d.symbol+'</div><div class="price">'+d.price+'</div></div>
<div class="myPrice"><div class="symbol">'+d.symbol+'</div><div class="price">'+d.price+'</div></div>
</div>
```

how can i select 2nd div.price in css?
(data gotten from url)

Comment: `.myPrice:nth-child(2) .price`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nth-of-type vs nth-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313769/nth-of-type-vs-nth-child)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wanting to select the second elements from within the class wholePrice elements. Then you need to select the class price element.

This snippet may have more specificity than you need, but without knowing the context it's not possible to know whether it's safe to drop any of the parts of the selector:

```css
#wholePrice .myPrice:nth-child(2) .symbol+.price {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="wholePrice">
  <div class="myPrice">
    <div class="symbol">'+d.symbol+'</div>
    <div class="price">'+d.price+'</div>
  </div>
  <div class="myPrice">
    <div class="symbol">'+d.symbol+'</div>
    <div class="price">'+d.price+'</div>
  </div>
  <div class="myPrice">
    <div class="symbol">'+d.symbol+'</div>
    <div class="price">'+d.price+'</div>
  </div>
</div>
```