# How can I display border from the correct division?

Tags: html, css, sass

I need to apply CSS from 10th div element. I've to start bordering from 10th div.bfaText element. I'm not sure why it its starting from 5th div element. I've also added CSS .bfaText:nth-child(n + 10) but its not working, not sure what wrong am I doing. I'm unable to find the root cause for this. Need an help on this.

```css
.bfaText:nth-child(n + 10) {
    border: 2px solid orange;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
    padding-left:10px;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pt-5 lmn-pb-5 crListDivision ng-star-inserted">
    <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-row lmn-mx-0 ng-star-inserted">
        <ul _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group lmn-list-group-initial ng-star-inserted">
            <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item lmn-list-group-item-noinitial lmn-font-weight-bold" style="font-size: 12px !important;">TSPM Metadata Validation (01)</li>
            <ol _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group lmn-list-group-initial">
                <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
                    <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007127">
                        CR IN 10007127
                    </a>
                    <!--container-->
                </li>
                <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
}-->
                <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted"></div>
                <!--ng-container--><!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
}-->
            </ol>
        </ul>
        <!--ng-container-->
        <ul _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group lmn-list-group-initial ng-star-inserted">
            <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item lmn-list-group-item-noinitial lmn-font-weight-bold" style="font-size: 12px !important;">TSPM Process Connector Validation (19)</li>
            <ol _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group lmn-list-group-initial">
                <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
                    <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007128">
                        CR IN 10007128
                    </a>
                    <!--container-->
                </li>
                <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
}-->
                <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">Optima Retail | R06.71.1-Calculate Expected and Unexpected Loss by Portfolio | FUNC001561-Numeric Reference Capturing</div>
                <!--ng-container-->
                <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
                    <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007123">
                        CR IN 10007123
                    </a>
                    <!--container-->
                </li>
                <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
}-->
                <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">Manual | R06.71.10-Review Categorization and Record Overrides | FUNC001141-Hedging Monitoring</div>
                <!--ng-container-->
                <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
                    <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007125">
                        CR IN 10007125
                    </a>
                    <!--container-->
                </li>
                <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
}-->
                <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">Manual | R06.71.11-Finalize Categorization | FUNC001142-Hedging Strategy Determination</div>
                <!--ng-container-->
                <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
                    <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007118">
                        CR IN 10007118
                    </a>
                    <!--container-->
                </li>
                <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
}-->
                <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">Manual | R06.71.12-Generate 360 Metrics Dashboard | FUNC001328-Legal Entity Requested</div>
                <!--ng-container-->
                <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
                    <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007122">
                        CR IN 10007122
                    </a>
                    <!--container-->
                </li>
                <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
}-->
                <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">CitiRisk Retail | R06.71.13-Monitor Concentration Risk, Other Portfolio Limits &amp; Breaches | FUNC001329-Legal Judgment</div>
                <!--ng-container-->
                <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
                    <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007109">
                        CR IN 10007109
                    </a>
                    <!--container-->
                </li>
                <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
}-->
                <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">Manual | R06.71.13-Monitor Concentration Risk, Other Portfolio Limits &amp; Breaches | FUNC001329-Legal Judgment</div>
                <!--ng-container-->
                <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
                    <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007115">
                        CR IN 10007115
                    </a>
                    <!--container-->
                </li>
                <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
}-->
                <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">
                    Manual | R06.71.14-Perform Balanced Scorecarding &amp; Breach Detection | FUNC001330-Legal Opinion and Comfort Letter Drafting and Negotiation
                </div>
                <!--ng-container-->
                <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
                    <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007106">
                        CR IN 10007106
                    </a>
                    <!--container-->
                </li>
                <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
}-->
                <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">Manual | R06.71.2-Allocate Finance Balances | FUNC001562-Obligor Risk Rating Determination</div>
                <!--ng-container-->
                <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
                    <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007124">
                        CR IN 10007124
                    </a>
                    <!--container-->
                </li>
                <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
}-->
                <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">
                    GENESIS - North America Core | R06.71.3-Input Portfolio Data and Check for Completeness | FUNC001128-Greenlight or Round Table Meeting
                </div>
                <!--ng-container-->
                <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
                    <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007126">
                        CR IN 10007126
                    </a>
                    <!--container-->
                </li>
                <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
}-->
                <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">CitiRisk Retail | R06.71.3-Input Portfolio Data and Check for Completeness | FUNC001128-Greenlight or Round Table Meeting</div>
                <!--ng-container-->
                <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
                    <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007119">
                        CR IN 10007119
                    </a>
                    <!--container-->
                </li>
                <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
}-->
                <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">Manual | R06.71.3-Input Portfolio Data and Check for Completeness | FUNC001128-Greenlight or Round Table Meeting</div>
                <!--ng-container-->
                <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
                    <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007121">
                        CR IN 10007121
                    </a>
                    <!--container-->
                </li>
                <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
}-->
                <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">
                    Enterprise Data Warehouse (EDW) - APAC | R06.71.4-Conduct Data Quality Checks | FUNC001129-Greenshoe Option Exercise and Disclosures
                </div>
            </ol>
        </ul>
        <!--ng-container-->       
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your html seems invalid, `<div>`  cannot be a direct child of `<ol>`. This might cause the issues with nth-child not targeting the correct element

Comment: where is bfaText? can you provide enough html?

Comment: @pierfarrugia <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">Manual | R06.71.12-Generate 360 Metrics Dashboard | FUNC001328-Legal Entity Requested</div> Plz check, I've provided enough HTML

Comment: you target childs, but each a `div.bfaText` comes with an `li` sibling. So you then need to double your selector to `n + 20`. The selector `:nth-child()` just counts any child, regardless tag type or class https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: Please take a look at this question's answer:
[nth-of-type-vs-nth-child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9313769/nth-of-type-vs-nth-child)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because when you use nth-child code you count all child of ol element I  suggest you to use nth-of-type instead of nth-child that can count elements by type :)

```css
.bfaText:nth-of-type(n + 10) {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

li:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pt-5 lmn-pb-5 crListDivision ng-star-inserted">
  <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-row lmn-mx-0 ng-star-inserted">
    <ul _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group lmn-list-group-initial ng-star-inserted">
      <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item lmn-list-group-item-noinitial lmn-font-weight-bold" style="font-size: 12px !important;">TSPM Metadata Validation (01)</li>
      <ol _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group lmn-list-group-initial">
        <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
          <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007127">
                                CR IN 10007127
                            </a>
          <!--container-->
        </li>
        <!--bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
        }-->
        <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted"></div>
        <!--ng-container-->
        <!--bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object]"
        }-->
      </ol>
    </ul>
    <!--ng-container-->
    <ul _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group lmn-list-group-initial ng-star-inserted">
      <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item lmn-list-group-item-noinitial lmn-font-weight-bold" style="font-size: 12px !important;">TSPM Process Connector Validation (19)</li>
      <ol _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group lmn-list-group-initial">
        <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
          <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007128">
                                CR IN 10007128
                            </a>
          <!--container-->
        </li>
        <!--bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
        }-->
        <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">Optima Retail | R06.71.1-Calculate Expected and Unexpected Loss by Portfolio | FUNC001561-Numeric Reference Capturing</div>
        <!--ng-container-->
        <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
          <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007123">
                                CR IN 10007123
                            </a>
          <!--container-->
        </li>
        <!--bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
        }-->
        <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">Manual | R06.71.10-Review Categorization and Record Overrides | FUNC001141-Hedging Monitoring</div>
        <!--ng-container-->
        <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
          <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007125">
                                CR IN 10007125
                            </a>
          <!--container-->
        </li>
        <!--bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
        }-->
        <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">Manual | R06.71.11-Finalize Categorization | FUNC001142-Hedging Strategy Determination</div>
        <!--ng-container-->
        <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
          <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007118">
                                CR IN 10007118
                            </a>
          <!--container-->
        </li>
        <!--bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
        }-->
        <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">Manual | R06.71.12-Generate 360 Metrics Dashboard | FUNC001328-Legal Entity Requested</div>
        <!--ng-container-->
        <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
          <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007122">
                                CR IN 10007122
                            </a>
          <!--container-->
        </li>
        <!--bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
        }-->
        <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">CitiRisk Retail | R06.71.13-Monitor Concentration Risk, Other Portfolio Limits &amp; Breaches | FUNC001329-Legal Judgment</div>
        <!--ng-container-->
        <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
          <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007109">
                                CR IN 10007109
                            </a>
          <!--container-->
        </li>
        <!--bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
        }-->
        <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">Manual | R06.71.13-Monitor Concentration Risk, Other Portfolio Limits &amp; Breaches | FUNC001329-Legal Judgment</div>
        <!--ng-container-->
        <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
          <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007115">
                                CR IN 10007115
                            </a>
          <!--container-->
        </li>
        <!--bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
        }-->
        <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">
          Manual | R06.71.14-Perform Balanced Scorecarding &amp; Breach Detection | FUNC001330-Legal Opinion and Comfort Letter Drafting and Negotiation
        </div>
        <!--ng-container-->
        <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
          <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007106">
                                CR IN 10007106
                            </a>
          <!--container-->
        </li>
        <!--bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
        }-->
        <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">Manual | R06.71.2-Allocate Finance Balances | FUNC001562-Obligor Risk Rating Determination</div>
        <!--ng-container-->
        <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
          <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007124">
                                CR IN 10007124
                            </a>
          <!--container-->
        </li>
        <!--bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
        }-->
        <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">
          GENESIS - North America Core | R06.71.3-Input Portfolio Data and Check for Completeness | FUNC001128-Greenlight or Round Table Meeting
        </div>
        <!--ng-container-->
        <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
          <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007126">
                                CR IN 10007126
                            </a>
          <!--container-->
        </li>
        <!--bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
        }-->
        <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">CitiRisk Retail | R06.71.3-Input Portfolio Data and Check for Completeness | FUNC001128-Greenlight or Round Table Meeting</div>
        <!--ng-container-->
        <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
          <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007119">
                                CR IN 10007119
                            </a>
          <!--container-->
        </li>
        <!--bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
        }-->
        <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">Manual | R06.71.3-Input Portfolio Data and Check for Completeness | FUNC001128-Greenlight or Round Table Meeting</div>
        <!--ng-container-->
        <li _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-list-group-item crList ng-star-inserted">
          <a _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" target="_blank" placement="top" ng-reflect-placement="top" href="" ng-reflect-mt-tooltip="10007121">
                                CR IN 10007121
                            </a>
          <!--container-->
        </li>
        <!--bindings={
          "ng-reflect-ng-if-else": "[object Object]"
        }-->
        <div _ngcontent-tpq-c266="" class="lmn-pb-2 lmn-font-size-xs bfaText ng-star-inserted">
          Enterprise Data Warehouse (EDW) - APAC | R06.71.4-Conduct Data Quality Checks | FUNC001129-Greenshoe Option Exercise and Disclosures
        </div>
      </ol>
    </ul>
    <!--ng-container-->
  </div>
```